# Can I create a really Universal USB Drive?

Tags: grub2, usb, live-usb

I have looked and looked over this forum and multiple other forums about the correct way to do this and I have not found a solid answer yet. I am trying to create an all in one bootable tech USB drive.

I currently have 4 partitions on this 500 GB drive.

> 1 is Windows 8,
>   2 is Ubuntu 13.04,
>   3 is swap for Ubuntu, and
>   4 I'm calling Bootable ISOs.

This is what I want to happen. When I boot to the USB it goes to grub2 then from there I can go to Win8 or Ubuntu. So far all this works fine, However what I can't seem to get to work is I'm wanting to add tons and I mean around 300 GBs worth of Bootable ISOs, including Hirens, Bitdefender, ERD, and anything else I can get my hands on. Now I've heard all that is possible, however I am also wanting to be able to put Win8,Win7,WinVista,WinXP, and pretty much anything else that I may possibly use at work, and be able to install them all from my USB.

Think PXE server, but from my USB. Is all this possible. My first step was to install win8 and Ubuntu side by side, and I got that done. My next step has been to get Grub2 to boot to the .iso files on the 4th partition.

Any ideas, I'm kinda new to all this Ubuntu stuff, but I'm always willing to learn. So break it down for me as best as possible so that I can actually learn for next time.

Comment: May work for some in grub... but is highly complex http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847 , and won't work for all. Maybe this http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008S4XY08

Comment: The methods used by MultiBootUSB ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518273 ), will do much of what you want using grub2 to boot the iso's. If you try the script with the systems you require, you will get a good idea how to modify grub.cfg. Windows 7 installer requires an NTFS formatted partition, I'm not sure exactly how you would fit this onto a multi disk, but it should be possible to get it to boot using grub 2. What I don't understand is why this question was closed???